# If I skip merge commits when adding commits from develop to main will that cause issues?

Tags: git

So let's say I am in the development branch cherry pick 1 commit, and I skip the next commit which is a merge commit.

Then I merge that new branch into master.

Will this cause issues because the merge commit wasn't merged into master?

Comment: It would be an issue if there were changes that were applied on the merge commit (say, conflict resolutions.... or other changes).... if that is not the case, then nothing is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can cause issues. Merge commits can contain conflict resolutions and you would miss those if you skip the merge commit.

Note that a conflict is not only what `git` reports as a conflict (two commits editing the same line of a file, sometimes called a "textual conflict"). `git` would report those conflicts again when you try to merge your new branch into master. You would have to resolve it again, but at least you get a hint about the conflict.

But there is this other type of conflict sometimes called a "functional merge conflict" where two changes are incompatible with each other without being a textual conflict. The canonical example is person A renaming a function and person B introducing new code that invokes this function by its former name. In this case the merge commit would (should?) contain the renaming of the function in the newly introduced code, a change that is not present in the commit of person A nor in the commit of person B. Spotting (and resolving) those functional merge conflicts requires some effort and you would loose that if you skip the merge commit.